# Expected value of $|X|$ given $X$ when $X$ is standard normal

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, conditional-expectation, expected-value

Considering $X\sim N(0,1)$, I would like to know why

$$E\left[|X|\mid X \right] = |X|$$

I tried to prove that with the definition of expected value, but I've failed.
I would like to see the formal calculation/proof for that.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/od1UG.jpg)

Comment: What is your definition of conditional expectation? With the usual definition there is nothing to prove here except for observing that $|X|$ is measurable w.r.t. sigma field generated by $X$.

Comment: Yes I mean the usual definition to conditional expectation.
I dont get what you mean by: "  for observing that |X| is measurable w.r.t. sigma field generated by X"

Comment: If you show your attempt we would know what deifinition you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall the general rule, that if $\varphi(x) = \mathbb{E}[Y \: | \: X=x]$, then $\varphi(X) = \mathbb{E}[Y \: | \: X]$.

It should be obvious, that $P(|X|=|x| \: | \: X = x) = 1$, and therefore 
$$ \mathbb{E}[|X| \: | \: X=x] =|x|,$$
from which we conclude that $\mathbb{E}[|X| \: | \: X] = |X|$.

Comment: Remark: The result holds regardless of the assumption, that $X \sim N(0,1)$.

Comment: Thank you very much